# How to display 1 out of 2 possible fields values in same column : visual force

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, rendered, conditional

I have a column that needs to display date if there is no condition else display a combination of text+date if a criteria is met.

I have to append a text **Week Of**  to a date field  if a custom field  **material_group__c** in Object1 has certain values N2, A. I want to achieve this only using **VISUALFORCE**.

Following is what I tried...

> ATTEMPT 1

```
                   <apex:column title="Estimated Delivery Date at time of Order" rendered="{!OR(p.gew_material_group__c = 'N2', p.material_group__c = 'A')}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">EDD</apex:facet>              
                     <apex:outputText value="Week Of- {0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}" > 
                        <apex:param value="{!p.planned_ship_date__c}"/> 
                     </apex:outputText> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}" rendered="{!OR(NOT(p.material_group__c = 'N2'), NOT(p.material_group__c = 'A'))}"> 
                        <apex:param value="{!p.planned_ship_date__c}"/> 
                    </apex:outputText>
                 </apex:column>
```

> ERROR 1: Show visualforce codes on column instead of value that is within **" "** double quotes,
>   without throwing any error
>
> ATTEMPT 2

```
                 <apex:column title="Estimated Delivery Date at time of Order">
                     <apex:facet name="header">EDD</apex:facet>              
                      <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'N2',p.material_group__c = 'L2'),'week of-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}','{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}')}">
                        <apex:param value="{!p.planned_ship_date__c}" />                            
                    </apex:outputText>
```

> ERROR 2:  Incorrect parameter type for operator '/'. Expected Number,
>   received Text

But it seems, i can't have two apex:outputText  on the same column. So how should I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: In attempt 2: shouldn't your date format be enclosed within single quotes too ?

Comment: Did you mean like this '{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}' ??

Comment: Only trouble I'm facing is to add a string text as prefix to a date field, If I add 'week of-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}' the text part is causing trouble. Is there a better way?

Comment: Actually no, I'm wrong. It's just that your second error message appears to indicate that the / is misinterpreted by the parser. Your format in Attempt 2 looks ok. Did you by any chance mix up the errors or attempts ?

Comment: In case it helps, you can often use `<apex:outputPanel layout="none">...</apex:outputPanel>` to wrap multiple tags in contexts where only one is allowed to keep Visualforce happy with no extra markup emitted in the HTML.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I have updated the attempt 2 syntax, but the error still stands the same. I'm trying really hard to find the correct syntax. What does this mean "Expected Number, received Text"? text as in after adding "week of"?

Comment: Thnx @KeithC. Will try your suggestion too!

Comment: @MnZ  "Expected Number, received Text" would imply that the visualforce parser is trying to execute the / as a division.  Or, at least that's what I believe, and is somewhat suprizing me.

Comment: As @neff suggested  <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.gew_material_group__c = 'N2',p.gew_material_group__c = 'P2'),'Week Of-{0, date, MM//d//yyyy}','{0, date, MM//d//yyyy}')}">  worked for me. Thanks guys! Learnt a lot today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Attempt 2**

There is an error in second attempt. You don't want to enclose '/' within quotes. Please try following - it worked for me:

```
<apex:column title="Estimated Delivery Date at time of Order">
    <apex:facet name="header">EDD</apex:facet>              
        <apex:outputText value="{!IF(
            OR(p.material_group__c = 'N2', p.material_group__c = 'L2'),
            'week of-{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}', '{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}'
        )}">
            <apex:param value="{!p.planned_ship_date__c}" />                            
        </apex:outputText>
```

**Your Attempt 1**

I wanted to help here as well but I could't find an error in this approach. I copied your example and tried in one of my tables but it was working fine.

Comment: Hi @neff. Your prev answer worked for me. Double forward slash did the trick.  Please post that as answer. FYI  <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.gew_material_group__c = 'N2',p.gew_material_group__c = 'P2'),'Week Of-{0, date, MM//d//yyyy}','{0, date, MM//d//yyyy}')}"> WORKED for me

Comment: Hi @MnZ, at first I thought about double slashes but it was generating double quotes on my page. Are you sure that single slashes are not enough? They worked for me

Comment: Single slashes worked if there was no text attached to it, in this case "Week Of". Could you post what u tried? Double slashes accepted text prefixes as well as displayed proper date format in my case.

Comment: Single quotes example: <apex:outputText value="{!IF(
            true,
            'week of-{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}', '{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}'
        )}">
            <apex:param value="{!Service__c.My_Date_Field__c}" />                            
        </apex:outputText>. It displays "week of- 10/14/2014". That's strange :-)

Comment: Sorry @neff my mistake ...here's the correct one again ......'Week Of-{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}','{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}') totally worked.! thnx to u

Comment: That's great that it worked, good to hear that. It's also a relief that there's no magic here and same version works for me and you :-) So the version from my answer is fine.

Comment: That's right. Accepted!

Comment: It's about to be 3 years today since I asked this question, funny because I have come back to refer to this solution again :D